# SetWindowLong with DWL_MSGRESULT

Tags: c++, c, listview, winapi

So far as I know, `SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam))` where `CustomDraw` is my custom draw procedure, sets the return value of `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` and after this returns true:

```cpp
SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam));
return TRUE;
```

How is it possible that it sets the return value and this value is pointer to `CustomDraw()` and after it it returns true so it returns 2 values?

Where does `DialogBox()` exactly return values?  Are these values processed further, or they are just skipped?

How is it possible if it sets the return value that `CustomDraw(LPARAM lParam))` gets called more than one time? I mean, how does `SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT(LONG)CustomDraw(lParam));` make it to call so many times, how it needs to get the appropriate message?

What's the difference between `return SetWindowLong(...)` and between return pointer to custom draw?

```cpp
case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
{
    LONG_PTR p = 0;
    p = SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam));
    return  TRUE; // why  return (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam)) wont work if setwindowlong "set return value " of message so of  NM_CUSTOMDRAW
}
```

```cpp
LRESULT __stdcall CustomDraw (LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;

    switch(lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT : //Before the paint cycle begins
            return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: //Before an item is drawn
        {
            return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        }
        break;

        case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: //Before a subitem is drawn
        {
            switch(lplvcd->iSubItem)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(255,255,255);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(240,55,23);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;

                case 1:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(255,255,0);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(0,0,0);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;  

                case 2:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(20,26,158);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(200,200,10);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;

                case 3:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(12,15,46);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(200,200,200);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;

                case 4:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(120,0,128);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(20,200,200);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;

                case 5:
                {
                    lplvcd->clrText   = RGB(255,255,255);
                    lplvcd->clrTextBk = RGB(0,0,150);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
}
```

Comment: always use `SetWindowLongPtr` with `DWLP_MSGRESULT`

Comment: [Returning values from a dialog procedure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923).

Comment: @IInspectable this article dont answer on every question

Comment: It wasn't posted as an answer, so, yes, it is expected to not be a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

`SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam));` does not return a pointer to `CustomDraw()`.  It *calls* `CustomDraw()` first, then sets the `dwNewLong` parameter of `SetWindowLong()` to the return value of `CustomDraw()`.

As for why `DWL_MSGRESULT` is needed, that is covered in the documentation:

[NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw)

> Return value
>
> The value your application can return depends on the current drawing stage. The `dwDrawStage` member of the associated [NMCUSTOMDRAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmcustomdraw) structure holds a value that specifies the drawing stage. You must return one of the following values.
>
> ...
>
> **If this message is handled in a dialog procedure, you must set the return value as part of the window data before returning TRUE.** For more information, see [DialogProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc).

[DLGPROC callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc)

> Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE if it processed the message, and FALSE if it did not. If the dialog box procedure returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message.
>
> **If the dialog box procedure processes a message that requires a specific return value, the dialog box procedure should set the desired return value by calling `SetWindowLong(hwndDlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, lResult)` immediately before returning TRUE.** Note that you must call `SetWindowLong` immediately before returning TRUE; doing so earlier may result in the `DWL_MSGRESULT` value being overwritten by a nested dialog box message.

So, the code is handling `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` by:

- calling `CustomDraw(lParam)`
- then setting its return value to `DWL_MSGRESULT` to return the value to the caller that issued `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`
- then returning `TRUE` to indicate to `DialogBox()` that the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message was processed

Comment: okay but whats going on with this return value and what process return value ? if DefDlgProc process  value like that  BOOL_PTR fResult = DialogProcedure(hdlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    if (fResult) return GetWindowLongPtr(hdlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT);  where it return this value

Comment: The **original sender** of the message processes whatever value is `return`'ed to it *after* the `DialogProcedure()` is called. If the `DialogProcedure()` returns `TRUE`, the sender is `return`'ed the value saved in `DWLP_MSGRESULT`. Otherwise, if the `DialogProcedure()` returns `FALSE`, `DialogBox()` itself processes the message as needed and `return`'s an appropriate value. I don't understand why this is hard to understand. This is all documented behavior.